# How to create (n) objects in c# based on loop

Tags: c#

Say I want to create (n) DataTables named DT(n)... how can I go about that in a loop.

Pseudo code below

```
int n=99;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    DataTable DT + n = new DataTable(); // <--- this
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use an array?

Comment: No, that is not possible. But you could make an array of DataTables or some other collection of them.

Comment: Use [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't have dynamic variable names in C#.

You can however, put them into an array (this is a much better approach anyways):

```
int n=99;
DataTable[] DT = new DataTable[99];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    DT[i] = new DataTable();
}
```

Comment: This is much more likely to be helpful to the OP than the fancier answers.

Answer (score 5):

Store them in a data structure.

```
Enumerable.Range(0,n).Select(x => new DataTable()).ToArray()
```

Comment: or simply  Enumerable.Repeat(new DataTable(), n)

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's going to give you `n` references to the same instance of `DataTable`, not `n` instances of `DataTable`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create dynamically named variables in C#.
For your purpose you are better off using Arrays or Dictionaries ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<DataTable> DTs = new List<DataTable>();
int n =99;
for(int(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DTs.Add(DT);
}
```

Comment: `New` is VB, `new` is C#. They don't mix :)

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the contents. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one

```
public List<T> CreateObjects<T>(int numbers) where T: new()
{
   List<T> _return = new List<T>();
   for (int i = 0; i <= numbers; i++)
   {
      _return.Add(new T());
   }

   return _return;

}
```

to use

```
var myList = CreateObjects<DataTable>(100);
var myList = CreateObjects<AnyClass>(100);
```

use any object type

Comment: While a nice, generic piece of code, this has no explanation and is effectively the same as the LINQ answer (but much more confusing since the question was never about generics).

Comment: yes I know, but this is just a example for get idea