# How does one instantiate a class dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, class, runtime, instance, instantiation

I need to create an unknown number of instances of a class and be able to keep track of them in run time. Example User will say they want to create _n number of cars. The application then instantiates car01 - car_n, and as the application runs the user can use car"X" and the instance will keep track of its own mileage. How do I instantiate an instance of a car and how do I reference a specific instance?
I know I could have the class and a ludicrous number of pre-defined cars, but it just seems that if users want to create 5 or 6 cars, the code could pop out car1-car6.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Foo[] FooCar = new Foo[5];
        string[] _NamesForFoo = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf" };
        int FoosToMake = rnd.Next(1, _NamesForFoo.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < FoosToMake; i++)
        {                
            FooCar[i] = new Foo(_NamesForFoo[i], rnd.Next(100,500));
            Console.WriteLine("You just created a FooCar named {0} with a count of {1}.", 
            FooCar[i]._FooName, FooCar[i]._FooCount);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string _FooName { set; get; }
        public int _FooCount { set; get; }

        public Foo(string _NameIn, int _CountIn)
        {
            _FooName = _NameIn;
            _FooCount = _CountIn;
        }
    }
}
```

The link provided in the response does not answer the question to this example. The collection, or list, did not work either. Here is an example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string[] _NamesForFoo = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf" };
        int FoosToMake = rnd.Next(1, _NamesForFoo.Length);

        List<Foo> FooCar = new List<Foo>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < FoosToMake; i++)
            {                
                new Foo(){_FooName = _NamesForFoo[i], _FooCount = rnd.Next(100,500)};
            }
        };
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string _FooName { get; set; }
        public int _FooCount { get; set; }

        public Foo(string _NameIn, int _CountIn)
        {
            _FooName = _NameIn;
            _FooCount = _CountIn;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use any kind of collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create (n) objects in c# based on loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071671/how-to-create-n-objects-in-c-sharp-based-on-loop)

Comment: Using a collection is the obvious solution. The real problem is how to access the controls later on. This depends on your requirements. One option is to use a Dictionary and use a string as identifier. Another is to put them is a ListView and let the user select a CurrentCar from it.. Both are not mutually exclusive!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection:

```
var cars = new List<Car>();

for (int i = 0; i < NumCarsNeeded; i++)
{
    cars.Add(new Car());
}

//Access car #1 (index 0)
cars[0].Mileage += 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand it completely, but I think here is what you are looking for:

```
// To store common properties and methods, use an abstract class:
public abstract class Car {
  public string Make {get; set;};
  public string Model {get; set;};
// The rest of properties
}

// To store special data for a particular type of car:
public class Van: Car
{
   public string DoorType {get; set;}
   // the rest of properties
}

public class Truck: Car
{
//...
}
```

Then for instantiating and maintaining a list of cars, use polymorphism:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
Van v1 = new Van { Make="...", Model="...", DoorType="..." };
Truck t1 = new Truck { Make="...", Model="...", /*...*/ };

cars.Add(v1);
cars.Add(v2);

string doortype = (cars[0] as Van).DoorType;
string model = cars[0].Model;
```

I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an array of the class was a good way to go. Here's the example that worked.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Foo[] FooCar = new Foo[6];
        string[] _NamesForFoo = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf" };
        int FoosToMake = rnd.Next(1, _NamesForFoo.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Making {0} FooCars.", FoosToMake);
        //create the cars
            for (int i = 0; i < FoosToMake; i++)               
            {                
                FooCar[i] = new Foo( _NamesForFoo[i], rnd.Next(100,500));
            }
        //list the cars
            for (int i = 0; i < FoosToMake; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FooCar {0} has a count of {1}", FooCar[i]._FooName, FooCar[i]._FooCount );
            }
        //modify a car
            FooCar[0]._FooCount += 2500;
        //show change to specific car
            Console.WriteLine("FooCar {0} now has a count of {1}", FooCar[0]._FooName, FooCar[0]._FooCount);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string _FooName { get; set; }
        public int _FooCount { get; set; }

        public Foo(string _NameIn, int _CountIn)
        {
            _FooName = _NameIn;
            _FooCount = _CountIn;
        }
    }
}
```